# Is there a pure CSS way to have a bar stay on the same place?

Tags: html, css

Similar to some Facebook feature, like the Chat link, that stays constantly at the same place of the page, regardless if you scroll.
Is there a simple pure CSS way to achieve this?
Here is a very simplistic HTML:

```
<div id='constant-bar'> some background some text</div>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
.... X 1000
<p>content</p>
```

I really care right now for IE>8 and FF > 5 and chrome, Safari latest versions. My code will be released only some time from today

Comment: Why down votes? Is this question illegal or subjective?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Research [`position:fixed`](http://www.google.com/search?gcx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=position%20fixed)**

It is not supported on many mobile browsers at the moment, and older Internet Explorer versions (IE<7) don't support it either.  Additionally, [IE 7 has a strange bug](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/position.html).

If you want it to stretch the full height of the page, you'll also have to look into that too.  [This tutorial might help](http://webdesign.about.com/od/csstutorials/f/set-css-height-100-percent.htm).

Answer (score 4):

look into the CSS attribute [fixed](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/position.html):

```
position: fixed;
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/fXRPr/)